# Build a string with spaces with either String builder or string class

Tags: c#, string, substring, stringbuilder

I need to make a long string, about 360 characters, with different values that I am sending to a service. I know the positions for each section and I need to be able to insert values and blanks until I get to the next position.
The following is just an example that I started; per say I need to start in position 0 and the next value needs to go in position 5(abc). So far I've been able to concatenate like this: *"1234abc"*, but what I need is **"1234[space]abc[space][space]"** Thanks for your help.

```
    //sbTrialSpaces
    private void TrialSpaces()
    {

        string str1 = "1234";
        string str2 = "abc";
        string finalStr;//Has to be 10 positions
        //like this "1234 abc  "

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string.Format("{0,-5}{1,-5}{2,-5}", val1, val2, val3);
```

This will make five spaces for each of the values, even if they are less than five characters wide. The "-" means that the values will be left-justified.

Comment: Thank you ALL for your great QUICK responses. I just tried this suggestion and suffice my needs. I'll definitely try the other responses when I have a chance, but for now I can move on. You all have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the StringBuilder like you suggested.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(str1);
sb.Append(" ");
sb.Append(str2);
sb.Append("  ");
string finalString = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var finalStr = ("1234" + " " + "abc").PadRight(10, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Join

```
String.Join(" ", myStrings);
```

Assuming myStrings is an IEnumerable of strings

Answer (score 0):

```
while (finalStr.Length < 10)
    finalStr += " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [Fixed Length](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/quick_start_fixed.html) format that [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) supports.

```
[FixedLengthRecord()] 
public class Order 
{ 
    [FieldFixedLength(5)] 
    public int OrderId; 

    [FieldFixedLength(30)] 
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)] 
    public string CustomerName; 

    [FieldFixedLength(10)] 
    public string SKU; 

    [FieldFixedLength(8)] 
    [FieldConverter(typeof(TwoDecimalConverter))] 
    public decimal Price; 

    [FieldFixedLength(8)] 
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")] 
    public DateTime AddedDate; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string finalStr = str1.PadRight(4,' ') + str2.PadRight(6,' ');
```

There is no need for a stringbuilder because you are adding it all at once.